# Should I convert this comment into an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

Yesterday I posted a comment on [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113201/efficiently-implementing-a-prime-sieve) with a link to an answer on StackOverflow that answered this question. Now the OP wants me to post it as an answer so they can accept it. I am not sure what to do because:

On one hand, this is the answer that the OP was looking for, so I want to post it as an answer.

On the other hand, I can't post just the link because I would flag that as "not an answer" and I don't feel like I should just copy someone else's answer into mine.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Flag it for closing (I just did), as it belongs on SO anyway, *and* it's a duplicate of an SO question.

Comment: @Cyclops That looks like it is probably right in this case, so I also flagged it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So don't just post a link. [Describe the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), note where you found the implementation and why it works so well, maybe go into a bit of detail on the shortcomings of the OP's naive design and how they're avoided...

You know, write a proper answer that can be read and understood without following a link or blindly copy-pasting code.

Comment: This looks like it is probably the best solution in general, but as Cyclops pointed out this particular question was a duplicate.